# Laravel reverse routing - route url needs query string attached

Tags: hyperlink, routes, laravel-4, query-string

In a view, I want to create a link (generate the url) to a route.  I believe this is called “reverse routing.”  I want to add a query string to the generated url.

The target routes need to take a query string parameter to specify what kind of view to return, e.g. partial, basic, full.  I will also be adding other query string params for search terms and fields.  I will need to pass these on to my api that is called with my dispatcher (consuming my own api).

```
Route::get('thing/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'path\to\namespace\ThingController@show',
    'as' => 'thng.show']);
Route::get('thing/form/{id?}', [
    'uses' => 'path\to\namespace\ThingController@form',
    'as' => 'thng.form']);
```

In a view:

```
<td>{{ link_to_route('thng.show?filter="partial"', $row->title,
                ['id' => $row->id])  }}</td>
```

I tried simply appending ?string to the route name within link_to_route, but that doesn't work (Error = Route [lstg.show?filter="partial"] not defined).  I'm not sure how to hard-code it either since it's a named route and does take a named route parameter.

Answer (score 1):

In your case I guess you should try something like this:

```
<td>{{ link_to_route('thng.show', $row->title, ['filter' => 'partial', 'id' => $row->id]) }}</td>
```

Note: Using `link_to_route` function you should distinguish URL parameters (query string) which is third argument and HTML attributes of anchor tag itself, which is last argument.

Comment: Using that 3rd param attaches the stuff as replacements to (substitutes for) named parameters (such as {id}) in the route *before* the ? for the query string.  I'm going with 'clean urls' and want these params after the ? on the url, as query string params, not route params.  I'm already passing an array for the named param substitution.  Maybe I should add to that array and see what happens.

Comment: omg it worked.  `{{ link_to_route('thng.show', $row->title,
['id' => $row->id, 'filter' => 'partial']) }}` yields `/thing/3?filter=partial` - cool!  Re: language, is "url params" generally considered inclusive of "query string params"?

Comment: Query string is a part of a URL following a question mark (http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/g/query-string.htm). URL params I guess is more general term, in your case 'id' could be considered as URL parameter.

Comment: Laravel is smart that way. When you generate the route by it's name, it knows darn well that `filter` is not a URL parameter, as it can only find `id`. So it automatically assumes it's a query parameter.